# Database Multiple Optional Filters with Null values in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to find the most optimal way to create conditional filtering of a Database in AnyLogic. The database, looks as follows:

[image]

What I am trying to do is adding in AnyLogic Main window 12 check boxes: P1, P2, P3, ..., T5, T6

If the user checks P1, with reference to the above table, A and B need to be displayed.
If the user checks P2, C needs to be displayed
If the user checks P1 and T2, A needs to be discplayed

In summary, it is like filtering in Excel any set of columns by "x" noting that the other cells have a null value.

To start, I used the following code to filter for P1 only (adding the entries to a collection of type String):

```
collectionDescription.addAll(  
selectFrom( data_base ).  
where( data_base.P1.eq("x")).  
list( data_base.Col1));
```

Now to filter for P2 as well, the following can be done:

```
collectionDescription.addAll(  
selectFrom( data_base ).  
where( data_base.P1.eq("x")).
where( data_base.P2.eq("x")).  
list( data_base.Col1));
```

Following the above logic, as many "where" conditions as needed can be added. However, there are so many possible combinations (e.g. P1/P2, P1/P2/P3, P1/P3, etc. you can imagine the amount of possible combinations).

So, I thought of a potential solution where I would add as many "where" conditions as there are columns, but instead of adding ".eq("x")", I would add ".eq(varP1)". If a checkbox (e.g. P1) is ticked, varP1 would be equal to "x" (varP1 being a variable of type String). But if the box is unticked, ideally varP1 should take a value that means "where anything" so that the condition would not make any impact. I did not manage to find a way to mimic this behavior.

Sorry for the long post, but I wanted to make sure the situation is as clear as possible. So am I on the right track? Any suggestions on how to fix this? Your suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you have a checkbox associated to a variable varP1 to define what you want... then you can do

```
selectFrom(db_table)
    .where(varP1 ? db_table.db_column.eq("x") : db_table.db_column.isNotNull().or(db_table.db_column.isNull()))
    .list();
```

where anything is what i here did as any value which is either null or not null... so if the box is checked then you will find x, otherwise you will find anything